# How to create all size layout in android studio by default Android 2.3.3

Tags: android, android-layout

Is there other way except manually create all the layout folder like "layout-small,layout-large,layout-xlarge" ? Is there any automated function in android studio can automatically create these folder while creating the project?

Comment: Most of the time you don't need them. What's the point to create them automatically then?

Comment: Instead of creating multiole layout files , try to use multiple dimens folders. It will reduce the apk size. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31914452/implementing-multiple-layout-for-multiple-screen-support-is-not-working/31914623#31914623

Comment: @KingofMasses while that's a better solution when possible, it isn't always possible.  And the difference in apk sizes is negligible.  Its real value is the fact you don't need to edit multiple layout files if you change something.

Comment: Yup. Agreed @GabeSechan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my suggestion,there is no need for creating different size of layouts because we have a library by which we can set all dimensions according to devices.You can get the answer from my [previous answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45316318/layout-for-different-screen-sizes-in-android)